# In HTML5 Canvas, can I make the y axis go up rather than down?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing a graph in Canvas and struggling with the fact that the y-axis is "backward." The origin is in the top-left corner, and increasing values go down rather than up.

```
(0,0)            (x,0)       (0,y) ^
      +-------------->             |
      |                            |
      |    CANVAS                  |     INSTEAD
      |    DOES THIS               |     OF THIS
      |                            |
      |                            +----------------->
(0,y) v                       (0,0)              (x,0)
```

I know that I can move the origin to the bottom-left corner using translate().

```
context.translate(0, canvas.height);
```

And I know that I can invert the y-axis using scale().

```
context.scale(1, -1);
```

That seems to work, except that it causes text to appear upside-down. Is there a way to make Canvas's coordinates work the way I expect?

Comment: My advice to my 10 years ago self is to use the [builder pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder). Instead of drawing directly on the canvas, create a model of the thing you're trying to draw and write code to translate a model to the canvas. That way, if you want to switch to another medium (such as SVG) later, you don't have to rewrite any code. All of you have to do is create a new translator.

Comment: It might be simplest to use the transformation, then fix it up for drawing text. That way you only need to override one function, not all of them. I guess we would also need to override anything that draws images.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For more modern setup, you can use `context.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.height)`. This flips y axis and moves the whole canvas one screenful.

More on available transformations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform

Comment: Just as a wee note - you'll also need to invert the pointer position for mouse events if you are handling any mouse logic.

Comment: Tom, how do you invert the pointer position for mouse events?

Comment: Unfortunately, this method also seems to flipping text now.

Answer (score 11):

I think you'd do much better to just get used to it. The origin is in the top left with most pixel-based video/screen APIs.

[Here's a discussion on the subject](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=567140).

Comment: It's pretty confusing though to have bounding box where `bottom > top`.

Comment: it's not really that confusing, when you think about it for a few minutes. It's actually far less arbitrary than the accepted wisdom that right>left (which is not true in a lot of human languages). The paradigm is that the top left corner is known, and all values go out from that. This is logical because it's the only thing we can actually count on when something renders inside an arbitrarily sized screen or document.

Comment: I think *document* is the key word here. Screens could go either way, depending on whether they're used to display text or Cartesian graphs; but the reason we often have the origin at an *upper* corner is because **documents** go top-to-bottom, not bottom-to-top, in almost all human languages (bottom to top is rare). HTML5 canvas follows that convention because HTML is based on a document concept (hence DOM). It's not about being pixel-based.

Answer (score 6):

Plot `graph_height - y`.

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/nVUUM/

```
<canvas></canvas>

<script>
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var c = e.getContext('2d');

function plot(x,y) {
  c.fillRect(x, e.height-y, 5, 5);  
}

plot(100,50);
plot(200,100);
</script>
```

Comment: Ugh. I've taken this approach, but after a while, having to do that on *every* call that involves a y coordinate is very tedious, error-prone, and needlessly cluttered. I would much rather use http://stackoverflow.com/a/33499668/423105

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you put the .scale I just tried this and it didn't work at first. You need to put the .scale between the moveTo();

`ctx.arc(50,50,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.scale(1,-1);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.stroke();`