# How can I make the Y-Axis in HTML 5 Canvas get more negative as you go down?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

It seems that everything we learned in grade school has been thrown out the window with HTML5 Canvas. I constantly have problems conceptually because I think in terms of the Y-Axis become more negative as you go down it. Is it possible to do this with `context.translate()`, and if so, how? I wasn't able to find another question like this on Stack Overflow. For now, here is some starter code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function get_Context() {
canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. Anything will help, but if you please, In addition to the code I would also like to know why the particular line(s) work. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: When I said anything will help, I do not want any JQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335400/in-html5-canvas-can-i-make-the-y-axis-go-up-rather-than-down

Comment: I don't want it like that. I want it to go downwards still but get negative. @Cheery

Comment: More specifically, I want the origin to stay put. @Cheery

Comment: this is exactly what you want. Origin at the top border (translate on the picture by link if confusing), positive direction up, so that everything below is negative. + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760897/html5-canvas-inverted-coordinate-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
context.scale(1, -1);
```

It will flip y axis.

Comment: It's worth noting that this would be a really bad habit to get into if you want to write code for anyone other than yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any graphical language you deal with these days will operate such that y==0 is the top of the screen and the values increase as you go down. Flash works the same way. The reason is that it would be ludicrous for all screen values to be negative, and all positive values to be above the viewport. This is just how graphical languages work. There are actually very few cases where this is a problem that can't be solved by flipping the sign. You certainly wouldn't need to translate the canvas to achieve any effect you wanted to; you're much better off just inverting whatever it is you're trying to do along the y-axis in your code.