# JavaScript Canvas translating up the y axis

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am reading ***Javascript for Kids*** by Nick Morgan and I produced the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id ="canvas" width ="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
            ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            if (fillCircle) {
                ctx.fill();
            }
            else {
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        var drawBee = function (x, y) {
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
            ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";

            circle(x, y, 8, true);
            circle(x, y, 8, false);
            circle(x - 5, y - 11, 5, false);
            circle(x + 5, y - 11, 5, false);
            circle(x - 2, y - 1, 2, false);
            circle(x + 2, y - 1, 2, false);

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I created a function called `circle` to draw some circles, and I wish to create two circles with black outlines above the centre of the original circle with values x and y.

As you can see, these circles have the code

```
circle(x - 5, y - 11, 5, false);
circle(x + 5, y - 11, 5, false);
```

But I thought similar to the x axis where moving to the right in the positive direction is `x + 5`, I thought moving **up** the y-axis in the positive scale is `y + 11`.

Why is it `y - 11` and not `y + 11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 0,0 is the top left-hand side, so adding to `y` goes down, and subtracting from `y` goes up. Using `x,y` notation:

```
0,0   1,0   2,0   3,0   4,0
0,1   1,1   2,1   3,1   4,1
0,2   1,2   2,2   3,2   4,2
0,3   1,3   2,3   3,3   4,3
0,4   1,4   2,4   3,4   4,4
```

If you added to `y` to go up, then 0,0 would be the *bottom* left-hand side.

And no, it's not crazy to think maybe it would be the lower left-hand side. I think *every* corner has been used as the 0,0 point by *some* coordinate system. For instance, 0,0 is the lower left-hand side in PDFs by default.

Comment: A moment of wow just went into my head! I understand now thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is the origin is in the top left of your screen instead of bottom left as expected so the way goes like this in case of y axis.
You can flip it if you want it using `context.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.height)`
For reference consider

[In HTML5 Canvas, can I make the y axis go up rather than down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335400/in-html5-canvas-can-i-make-the-y-axis-go-up-rather-than-down)

[Here is the discussion link you'll like to refer to](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/567140-reason-for-screen-coordinate-origin-on-top-left/)

Answer (score 0):

Long ago pixels were scanned from memory, starting at the lowest address (top left) to the highest (bottom right). Displays (CRT) would scan from left to right top to bottom, as pixels were read from memory in time to excite the corresponding phosphorus pixel on the screen. Converting from pixel address to x,y coordinate and back was thus naturally with the y axis down as it matched both the memory address direction (positive) and the time direction (positive in time). And in those days even the smallest optimisation was very important.

Now you can render via the transformation matrix that can set the direction of either axis independently (2D x,y) or in 3D (x,y,z) or more (x,y,z,w), though the raw pixel data is still from lowest address to highest for no other reason than conventions and compatibility.